# Unable to get Latitude in the Y field in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, csv, latitude-longitude, files

I have an issue, and I don't know to solve it. I've downloaded a CSV file which contains among other metadata latitude and longitude. I want to display them on the map. But I want to display that by right-clicking and selecting display XY; I get only longitude in all X and Y fields. I've tried to rearrange the columns manually by dragging or by choosing the fields options in the table properties.

The reference system is a GCS WGS 84.

Is there any other way to fix it?

Comment: can you share some x and y coordinates you have in your csv? It might be that some have a formatting error ("," instead of "." as decimal separator)

Comment: Another common error I come across is special characters in the field headings can throw off the recognition of fields in ArcMap. Also, try opening your CSV in Excel (spreadsheet software) and check that your first row contains your field headings correctly and the subsequent rows don't contain merged cells or other formatting issues.

Answer (score 2):

If formatting of the csv is right and the data will not load anyhow, check the file schema.ini inside the directory where your csv is stored. This file comes from a microsoft technique (odbc, jet) to load csv-files and ArcGIS uses this. It is automatically created when the csv is read by arcgis and determines the structure of the csv. Here you can specify data types for fields, field delimiter decimal symbol and more. It is documented on microsofts online docs: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/schema-ini-file-text-file-driver and mentioned in the arcgis documentation: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/adding-an-ascii-or-text-file-table.htm